# Automatic app download for android from firebase /appstore to Appium framework

Tags: android, appium, android-resources

I have created Appium framework for android using cucumber+serenity framework. Every time, I have to change my app manually under src/test/resource. Is there any way,code can automatically take latest test build app from firebase/apptester store ?

In that case, please help me with code.Usually how people will do that in their automation framework for long time running in Jenkins?